# Probability theorem proof: adding a constant to each of the outcomes

Tags: probability-theory

This is all I have so far... it sounds like a rather straight forward proof but I'm not really sure how to go about this. Also I don't understand how adding a constant to each outcome would be the same as just adding that constant at the end? If you add the constant to each outcome wouldn't that cause a greater result? Just trying some practice homework questions [image]

Answer (score 0):

The constant is added to the outcomes. You've added it to the product of outcome and probability. Your last line should say

$$
p_1(x_1+c)+p_2(x_2+c)+\cdots+p_n(x_n+c)\;.
$$

Then you can collect all the terms with the constant and use $\sum_ip_i=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes on the values $x_i$ with probability $p_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc, n$. Then
$$
EX=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ip_i
$$
and
$$
E(X+c)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+c)p_i=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ip_i+c\sum_{i=1}^np_{i}=EX+c
$$
since the probabilities sum to one.